# Ionic v4: The discrepancy in margin level between <ion-card> and <ion-list>

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I face a CSS issue when I am developing a weather app. So here's how it goes.

```
<ion-card *ngIf="...">

</ion-card>

<ion-list *ngIf="...">
    <ion-card></ion-card>
</ion-list>

<ion-card>
...
</ion-card>

<ion-card>
...
</ion-card>
```

Based on the data from the server, either the first `ion-card` or the ion-list will be called to return:

1. There is not an alert (`ion-card`);
2. There is(are) (a) alert(s). (`ion-list`)

However, I notice that there is a huge gap between the ion-list that shows that alert information and the `ion-card` that follows.

What I have tried:

1. Apply CSS style to the `ion-list` with !important.
2. Apply CSS style to the `ion-card` with !important.

[image: An illustration without any CSS added to ion-list or ion-card]

The first two cards, as shown above, are inside the ion-list(alert information). You will notice the huge gap between the second and the third `ion-card` - this is the result of the extremely large ion-list margin. I just have no idea how to resolve this issue. Can anyone help me out?

***Edit: The image doesn't seem to be uploaded.***

Comment: Is there any specific reason to add ion-list of card in between list of ion-card?